# React forEach not printing HTML in TSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, jsx, tsx

I'm using react with TSX and SCSS

I have searched before and I don't find an answer for this exact problem, so I think isn't duplicated.

I'm trying to do a `Header` component in React and I have an array of objects (Links) to add in the header.

The array is the following:

```
const menuLinks: menuLink[] = [
{
  title: "Home",
  path: "/",
  active: false,
},
{
  title: "about",
  path: "/about",
  active: false,
},
```

];

This links implements the following interface:

```
interface menuLink {
  title: string;
  path: string;
  active: boolean;
  [propety: string]: any;
}
```

I'm trying to do a `menuLinks.map(.....)` to print all the links inside a `<nav></nav>`.

The forEach im using is the next one:

```
return (
    <header className="header">
      <div className="logo"></div>
      <nav>
        {menuLinks.map((link, i) => {
          console.log("Entered", link);
          return <Link key={link.path + i} to={link.path} />;
        })}
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
```

I know for sure that the loop is being executed the correct times cause the console.log is executed correctly. The problem comes, when this loop does not print **ANYTHING** in the screen.

Any help or idea of why isn't working ?? I come from VueJS and React isn't my expertise.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm using .map()

Comment: Your code seems good ... What do you have when you inspect your DOM ? An empty ``<nav></nav>`` ? Could you log your menuLinks array aswell ?

Comment: You sure it's not a problem with your `Link` element instead? What if you just render a `<p>text</p>` instead, does that show up?

Comment: it seems that he doesn't use any forEach ... He's just mistaken between map and forEach :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is in `<Link />` there is no content, maybe try as:

```
<Link key={link.path + i} to={link.path}>{link.path}</Link>
```

That `.map()` seems fine other than this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue probably is that there is no content in the  element. Instead of `<Link />`, try `<Link>{link.title}</Link>`